# What is the smallest change in the following code snippet so that the output is "ABC"?

Tags: javascript

Hello I had this issue with my function

```
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, x) => x.concat(x.toUpperCase()));
console.log(string );
```

And in the final result I want to get "ABC"

Comment: `acc.concat` instead of `x.concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things

- apply `concat()` on `acc` not with `x`
- Set initial value of `acc` to `''` by passing it as second parameter of `reduce()`
- You can use `+` instead of `contat()`

```js
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, x) => acc+x.toUpperCase(),'');
console.log(string );
```

You can also do it using `map()` and `join()`

```js
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(x=>x.toUpperCase()).join('')
console.log(string );
```

Comment: @The silver dragon Its ok. Accept the one with which you are most satisfied. Ask if something is not clear or missing in my solution

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a string? `join()` to a string and `.toUpperCase()` is the direct and simple. Using `reduce()` is overkill.

```js
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].join('').toUpperCase();
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `concat()` with the accumulator `acc` string and also not passing the initial value of it which should be an empty string `""` (otherwise the first character of the resulting string would be lowercase as `toUpperCase()` won't be applied to it).

Learn more about **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**, this function takes the accumulator as the first param and the elements of the array as a second param and two other optional params.

```js
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.toUpperCase()), "");
console.log(string );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two misses.

- it should be `acc.concat(x.toUpperCase())`
- You missed `initial value` in reudce. else it will not change the `first` character to upper-case

```js
const string = ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.toUpperCase()),'');
console.log(string );
```

**On side note:-** You can simply use `+` instead of `concat`

Comment: @VLAZ so then you will get output as `aBC` which not required

Comment: Argh, I missed the capitalisation requirement. Sorry, you are correct.